# Parsing json data from database and view it in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system

Im retrieving data from my database in laravel then display the data into a blade template. I am using this code below:

```
if (Auth::check()) $users = User::all(); return view('view.users')->with('users', $users);
return redirect()->to('/auth/login');
```

When I display this into the blade template it returns the data I need but it has some curly braces {}. How do I display those data in the blade template?

Comment: you need to loop through it

Comment: I have looped it already, still has those curly braces but the data is fine.

Comment: hope u are not escaping the data, try `{!! $user->id !!}`  instead of `{{ $user->id }}` example `@foreach($users as $user)
   {!! $user->id !!}
@endforeach`

Comment: Tried that right now, still has those curly braces. :/ Data looks like this. { 1 Lyka akyl }. I have looped it with foreach and set the data still has those braces.

Comment: Ok thats wired. Please could you do a dump in your controller example: `$users = User::all(); dd($users);`

Comment: It returns this Collection {#182 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▶]
}

Comment: okay. one more thing. just to confirm that $users is okay, try this in your controller `$users = User::all();` `foreach($users as $user){
   echo $user->id, '<br>'; 
} `

Comment: It returns numbers 1 to 6. The number of users I currently have.

Comment: Okay this means the issue is from blade or something, $users object is fine. May I see code for in blade template?

Comment: I found the problem because of your comment. I did not know that when you use **@foreach @endforeach** in a blade template you don't need curly braces anymore, what happened is that my code had **@foreach { } @endforeach** inside so that was causing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: okay. I see, you are welcome. I have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blade you could use loop like so:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {!! $user->id !!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks a lot!